# Facebook puzzle error: throws it's automated mail regarding build/run error

Tags: c++, facebook, gcc, fizzbuzz

I solved the problem (Hoppity) as given on [Facebook Puzzle Page](http://www.facebook.com/careers/puzzles.php). I solved it in c++  language (using g++ compiler) and mailed the .cpp file as an attachment to the mentioned e-mail address. I didn't zip the file. After few hours I received a mail regarding run/build error. Can anyone please help me with this. Where m I going wrong?

Here's the code I submitted:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    long long i,n,k;
    ifstream fin("a.in");
    ofstream fout("output.in");
    fin>>n;
    k=n/15;
    for(i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
        fout<<"Hoppity"<<"\n";
        fout<<"Hophop"<<"\n";
        fout<<"Hoppity"<<"\n";
        fout<<"Hoppity"<<"\n";
        fout<<"Hophop"<<"\n";
        fout<<"Hoppity"<<"\n";
        fout<<"Hop"<<"\n";
    }
    for(i=k*15+1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        if(i%5==0) fout<<"Hophop"<<"\n";
        else if(i%3==0) fout<<"Hoppity"<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to see without seeing any code. Or error messages.

Comment: Regarding the lack of error messages, the automated mails by the PuzzleBot will simply state that "Unfortunately, your solution [...] could not be built and/or run. For security reasons, I cannot give out exact errors." (kind of annoying, really), so that's not the OP's fault.

Comment: Since you're emailing the .cpp: did you attach a makefile?

Comment: do we have to submit a makefile too..? can anyone please clear me regarding what all we have to mail besides the cpp file..??

Comment: Yes, you need to supply a Makefile: "If your solutions uses one of the compiled languages, it must be buildable using either GNU Make 3.81 or Ant 1.7.0 using the commands make or ant from the root directory where your submission is stored. You must supply your own makefiles or build.xml files."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What strikes me is that you do not take the name of your input file from the command line like the Hoppity puzzle demands. Instead, you read input from some "a.in" file.

Furthermore, you're expected to write the results to STDOUT, not some "output.in" file.